# reactjs props not passed to child

Tags: reactjs

I have specified this in the parent

```
openModal={this.state.openModal}
```

alongwith in state I have this defined

```
openModal : false
```

In the child component I access it like this

```
const { open } = this.props.openModal;
```

and I use it like this

```
open={open}
```

I get the error here

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `open` is marked as required in `Modal`, but its value is `undefined`.

Comment: Can you please add the components ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't declared your `open` variable correctly:

```
const { openModal } = this.props;
```

and then in your component:

```
open={openModal}
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't used destructuring correctly,

When you write

```
const { open } = this.props.openModal;
```

you are actually looking for `open` key in `openModal` object, however what you want is

```
const { openModal } = this.props;
```

which is equivalent to

```
const openModal = this.props.openModal;
```

After this you would write

```
open={openModal}
```